# upgraded to 13.04 now getting JREDetection "Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running

Tags: 13.04, java, google-chrome, security

I upgraded Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 upgraded java to 1.8.0-ea-b118 and still cannot run my application to connect to my office.
I have checked all the options and spent all day looking for hits on this issue but cannot fins a solution. Thanks.
Sorry meant to add that this is a url running in Chrome that starts a java program. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The following can be found [on this page](http://kde35.free.fr/blog/articles/2014/01/18/your-security-settings-have-bl.html)

Try to find the installation path of java control panel.  From the terminal

```
$locate jcontrol
/usr/bin/jcontrol
/usr/java/jre1.7.0_25/bin/jcontrol
/usr/java/jre1.7.0_25/lib/desktop/icons/HighContrast/16x16/apps/sun-jcontrol.png
....
/usr/java/jre1.7.0_51/bin/jcontrol
....
```

In this case /usr/java/jre1.7.0_51/bin/jcontrol is the one you want.  So launch it from terminal 
    /usr/java/jre1.7.0_51/bin/jcontrol
Then you will be able to change the security setting.

Comment: This worked for me. Although the site I was trying to run applet from was on http instead of https. So it didn't work even after changing security setting to Medium. I had to add the site to exceptions list.

Comment: Thank you. I solved my issue following this but in my case path was _/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jcontrol_

Answer (score 1):

Java no longer allows unsigned or self-signed applets to run by default.

You need to edit the file at `~/.java/deployment/deployment.properties` and add a line (or edit, if it exists) to set `deployment.security.level=MEDIUM`.

Additionally, see the advice here for enabling Java in the web browser on Ubuntu http://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser_ubuntu.xml

Comment: Clean and easy!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked and re-checked your java settings within Chrome?
What java are you using in Ubuntu?

- openjdk
- icedtea
- gcj

Have you tried the following in a terminal?

1. open up a terminal by pressing 'Ctrl'+'Alt'+'t',
2. enter this command after the prompt:
   `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force [PackageName]`
3. Enter, when prompted your sudo password,
4. Be sure to replace `[PackageName]` with your installed java product.

Besides java/security settings within Chrome, have you also got some active plugins/extensions installed, which might influence the working of java/java-applets?

The above steps can also be used to reconfigure your Chromium browser.
Before you try this, make sure you have made an export (backup) of your favourites.